# FullName, FullPath for Directory

Tags: c#, .net, directory

Why does a DirectoryInfo not provide a unified way to get the qualified name for a folder.

In this example:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        System.IO.DirectoryInfo DirInfo = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(@"C:\TEMP\");
        Console.WriteLine(DirInfo.FullName);
        System.IO.DirectoryInfo DirInfo2 = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(@"C:\TEMP");
        Console.WriteLine(DirInfo2.FullName);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Regardless if the directory actually exists, the FullName just reflects the userinput into the object, but you can't be certain you get a path with a "\" in the end.

In the MSDN documentation there is mentioned a inheritance from FileSystemInfo, where there is the possibility to retrieve the FQN by the property FullPath, but I can't seem to access it from an instance of DirectoryInfo.

Is there maybe a trick, or another method / field to get to be sure that the path always have the same format?

Comment: Why is this so important to you? What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm not sure what your actual question is. How to get always a \ at the end of a directory-path?

Comment: If you want to access files/directories inside this directory, you can use [`Directory.GetDirectories(path)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getdirectories?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_IO_Directory_GetDirectories_System_String_) or [`Directory.GetFiles(path)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getfiles?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_IO_Directory_GetFiles_System_String_) which include their Path and these should all have the same format

Comment: Hi thanks for you answers, I just weren't sure if the framework provides a property for this, because in productive scenarios I thought it would be easier if the output would be equalized in a way that nobody has to deal with additional code to achieve this, but I think this can be closed then.

Comment: @Rafalon thats a way for sure, in my case the directory has no files or dirs initially in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way or method to get the trailing backslash if it's not there. It's completely optional, but it also shouldn't make a difference for your program if it's there or not. But if you want to ensure it:

```
char[] blackslashes = {Path.DirectorySeparatorChar, Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar};
string dirPath = @"C:\TEMP";
if (!blackslashes.Contains(dirPath.Last()))
    dirPath += "\\";
System.IO.DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(dirPath);
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if i did understood your question correct ... but to get it unified, just use eg. a `Sanitize` method.

Example to always remove tailing backslash:

```
public string SanitizePath(string s) => s.TrimEnd('/', '\\');
```

Example to always add tailing backslash:

```
public string SanitizePath(string s) => s[s.Length - 1] == '/' || s[s.Length - 1] == '\\' ? s : String.Concat(s, '\\');
```

However, if the problem is invalid paths due to that inconsistency, chances are that you use `String.Concat` to build the full path.

You always should use `Path.Combine` for combining a path information as that should provide the proper output.

Comment: I like both your ways. Tims and yours, one has to be the answer so I would chose the first comer, but thanks for providing your input.